# How come my program takes so long to run?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2013

I have written a short code in C# in order to take out the text output generated from the Lyx software and modifies it so I could post it on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

The code assumes I have a file on my desktop called answer.txt, reads the file and then modifies the code, then it saves the output as answer2.txt at my desktop: For example, the text generated by Lyx have the first line "% Preview body" which I remove. another example is replacing

> \textbf{some text that should be bold}

with

> **some text that should be bold**

This is the code I have written:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\BelgiAmir\Desktop\answer.txt"))
        {
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string AfterFirstReplacement = text.Replace("\\[", "$$");
            string AfterSecondReplacement = AfterFirstReplacement.Replace("\\]", "$$");
            string RemovedPreviewHeader = AfterSecondReplacement.Replace("% Preview body", "");
            int indexOfBold ;
            while ((indexOfBold = RemovedPreviewHeader.IndexOf("\\textbf")) != - 1)
            {
                indexOfBold = RemovedPreviewHeader.IndexOf("\\textbf");
               int endIndex = RemovedPreviewHeader.IndexOf("}", indexOfBold);
               string boldedText = RemovedPreviewHeader.Substring(indexOfBold + 8, endIndex - indexOfBold - 8);
                RemovedPreviewHeader = RemovedPreviewHeader.Replace("\\textbf{" + boldedText + "}",
                    "**" + boldedText + "**");

            }
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\BelgiAmir\Desktop\answer2.txt", RemovedPreviewHeader);
        }
    }
}
```

But my code seems to be slow, at least I don't think it is reasonable run time.
I tested the code in the following manner: I have the two **empty** answer.txt and answer2.txt on my desktop. The .exe file is also on the same hard drive (and on the same partition). I have opened the .exe file and used a plain stopwatch to measure a running time of

> 15.5 seconds

The files (.exe and the .txt files) are located on an SSD, my computer have 8gb of ram and an i5 Haswell processor  (i5-4570). The OS is Windows 7 professional.

This seems like a very long running time - 15.5 seconds to open an empty .text file, then all string operations should be very fast as they are done on an empty string, and the while loop should not be preformed even once, then I save an empty file.

This is a code I have written a while ago and this is about the same running time I always get (even though I have restarted the computer since a couple of times and no "heavy" software is running on it)

Note: The code was written and compiled using VS 2013 express, I have tried running this test with both the Debug version of the .exe and both with a version for Release (and the running time was about the same)
Can someone suggest a reason for this long running time and how to fix it ?

**ADDED**: With running in Debug in VS and hitting F5 the code runs in less then two seconds! I don't know why it is so fast when I run it through VS then by opening the .exe file, can someone explain this ?

Comment: It's probably better to iterate over the text once, looking for a particular string that to do the same search over and over from the start.

Comment: Run it under the debugger and hit break about half-way through. Where is it stopped?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I agree that this could improve the preference, but not in the case that the string is empty as with the test -so this does not cause the slow running time

Comment: @Blorgbeard - With running in Debug in VS and hitting F5 the code runs in less then two seconds! I don't know why it is so fast when I run it through VS then by opening the .exe file

Comment: Ah, so sorry - missed the bit about the empty test files.

Comment: You could replace your entire `while` block with `RemovedPreviewHeader = Regex.Replace(RemovedPreviewHeader, @"\\textbf\{(.*?)\}", "**$1**", RegexOptions.Singleline);`. Even though technically this won't be really *correct* because it ignores the possibility of nested braces, it will provide the same functionality in one line.

Comment: your code runs really fast on my PC. StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds returns 0 or 1. The problem is in your PC

Comment: @mybirthname - Please see the "ADDED" part on the question

Comment: IndexOf function takes too long. You can do it with different way. Check this site. http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof you can see performance tests here.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski -  Please see the "ADDED" part on the question

Comment: Just a guess: I think this could be related to some access rights issue checking on the input file - a slow Active Directory lookup, or something like that. When you run in the debugger the access right is inherited from the parent process, perhaps.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Interesting. Is there something I could do ? (I run it again as Administrator thinking that since VS runs as Administrator  maybe this would do the trick, but no luck)

Comment: I would try running it under Process Explorer.

Comment: Sorry - make that [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) - also by Mark Russinovich. This one can log all API activity.